# How to join joomla tables

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have rudimentary SQL knowledge and am trying to apply what limited scope I have to figure out the following:

There a table called users that has an id (key) a name and an email (and other things I'm not overly concerned about). There's one entry for each user.

There's another table called usergroups that consists of an ID (key) and title. There are only two groups 'members' and 'associates'

There's a third table called user_group_map that has an ID and a groupid. The ID maps to the id in the users table. The groupid maps to the ID field in the usergroups table.

I'm trying to construct a select statement that will pick up all of the users in a given group.

I've become tongue-tied trying to figure out how to make that work. I can use phpMyAdmin to test SQL, but haven't much of an idea how to make the joins work right to filter usergroup and apply it backwards to users via the user_grou_map.

Guidance in SQL and/or joomla (preferably both so I can fatten my knowledge and do this generally) is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

josef

Comment: Details of tables, sample data and desired results will help your question.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange, you won't need to explain any of the core tables because the community will already be fully aware of them.  My advice is that you always ask your Joomla questions on JSE -- a place where you are virtually guaranteed to NOT receive pile-on downvotes ...even if you ask a suboptimal question.  Beyond that, yes, we need to understand the data in your core tables and your desired result.  A db-fiddle demo link would go far to complete your new question at JSE.

Comment: Oops. Sorry - thought I had, but I will look harder next time!

Comment: This question has been cross-posted (and improved) on JSE -- [How to join custom fields data to users table without extra rows in result set](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/31797/12352).

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 - use a subquery**

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM #__users WHERE id IN (
   SELECT user_id FROM #__user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id = 8
);
```

This will run the inner query first to retrieve all user ids in the group with ID 8. Then use those results in the outer query.

**Option 2 - use a join**

```
SELECT User.id, User.name, User.email FROM #__users as User 
LEFT JOIN #__user_usergroup_map as UserGroup on UserGroup.user_id = User.id
WHERE UserGroup.group_id = 8
```